# using explode function to read a string

Tags: php

My code reads a line from a file, splits the line into elements, and is supposed to put the elements in an array.

I used `explode`, but it does not put the elements into the array in sequential order.

Example: for input

```
line:   1000 3000 5000
```

This is what happens

```
$a=fgets($file); // $a= 1000 3000 5000
$arr= explode(" ",$a);
$u=$arr[3];    // $u=1000   
$w=$arr[6];    // $w=3000
$x=$arr[10];   // $x=5000
```

This is the desired order:

```
$u=$arr[0];    // $u=1000   
$w=$arr[1];    // $w=3000
$x=$arr[2];   // $x=5000
```

Why doesn't `explode` put data sequentially into the array?

Comment: what data are you getting in the other `array` parts? e.g. what is in `array[0]`, `array[1]`, `array[2]`,`array[4]`, etc...

Answer (score 1):

It always puts them in sequentially. IF you are seeing this behavior then you must have extra  in the document that are being exploded upon resluting in empty array elements. You will either need to pre-process the string or prune empty elements from the array.

Alternatively you could use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) with the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` setting.

Dome examples of that you are trying to do:

```
// using regex
$arr = preg_split("/ /", $a, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

// pruning the array
$arr = explode(" ", $a);
$arr = array_keys($a, '');
```

Comment: is there any way to let the code know to ignore all the empty spaces between numbers in a line?  Users create the original file and they can put one or more empty spaces between numbers. There is no restriction for users input in general.

Comment: Not with explode... you would have to use `preg_split` as i suggested for that or cleanup the string before using explode, or clean up the array after using it.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, it's going to put a new array entry per every space.

To get what you're looking for, the returned string would have to be "$u=1000_$w=3000_$x=5000" (underscores represent spaces here)

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way to do this would be to use array_filter to remove the empty elements i.e.

```
$arr = explode( ' ', $a ); // split string into array
$arr = array_filter( $arr ); // remove empty elements from array
$arr = array_values( $arr ); // strip old array keys giving sequential numbering, i.e. 0,1,2
```